# Protek 506 DMM: What capacitor is that?

Tags: capacitor, multimeter

[image: MAX134CMH MQFP44][[image: enter image 2][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNe6Z.png)

[image: description here]

[image: MAX134]

I have a Protek 506 DMM, and I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue.

I found a schematic diagram for the meter on the internet, but it is a copy of an original that has a fold in the middle, right where I am trying to read the value of C58 (I'm not sure if that is the capacitor's number, as the value and the name are on that crease).  The capacitor is mounted between pin 25 and the ground, on the MAX 134 ADC.  Pin 25 is connected to a resistor network, and is one of the four voltage ranges, but it is the only one that has a capacitor to ground on it.  Pin 25 is labelled  "1.11M", and the others are: 101K, 10K and 1K.

Any idea what the value of capacitor C58 would be?

Here is a link to download the PDF of the schematic diagram (6 pages):
https://elektrotanya.com/protek_hung_chang_506_dmm_sch.pdf/download.html#dl

The problem with this meter is that the the diode tester function is not working (won't change from displaying "OPEn" and 3.999V), nor the 4VDC range, and it appears that they are related somehow.  On the 4VDC range, the display alternates between showing 3.999V and 0V.  If a voltage is measured, say a 1.5V cell, then the display will alternate between showing 3.999V and 1.5V.

Comment: `The capacitor is mounted between pin 25 and the ground, on the MAX 134 ADC. Pin 25 is connected to a resistor network...` Pin 25 of [MAX134](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX133-MAX134.pdf) is NC (**N**o **C**onnection) on DIP40. Is it a PLCC package? Show a photo.

Comment: According to [MAX134 datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX133-MAX134.pdf), pin 25 is either NC or FILTER RESISTOR OUT, depending on package. Please show us a photo of the PCB showing the MAX134 and components around it.

Comment: Don't ask a question like this, I mean, assuming that everyone here knows the design and has the schematic at hand. So 1) include a schematic 2) include a photo of the component 3) include links to datasheets of any IC you mention.

Comment: OK.  I tried to add the PDF of the schematic diagram, but was not successful.  It seems only an image can be posted.  Anyone can please advise if I can post a PDF document?  I can add a link to where it can be downloaded, or simply search internet for "Protek 506 schematic diagram", and there are a number of sites that have that PDF.  The schematic shows a MAX 134CH-D, but it's hard to make out if that is the correct name, but it is a square 44pin SMD, about 17mm from foot end to end or 9mm of just the plastic body.  I'll take some photos of the PCB and attach them.

Comment: Please re-open this post, because I feel it was closed pre-maturely.  If people ask for more information, that is of course only natural, but it takes time for me to respond, because I have other commitments in life.  I can't see any need to close the post down, I've never been put to a time limit on a forum before.  Can someone please tell me if I can post a PDF of my meter's schematic diagram?  It seems that only picture images can be posted.

Comment: I've just added a photo of the MAX134CMH ADC that is on the Protek 506 PCB.

Comment: I can't see the capacitor in your photo! Read the ADC's datasheet and/or application notes to see what value it should be.

Comment: "*I've never been put to a time limit on a forum before.*" This isn't really a forum - it's a Q&A site. The [Tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) may help explain how the site operates. Closing poor questions quickly prevents people posting guesses as answers and reduces the amount of clutter on the site. A question can be reopened when it is improved. You can't post PDFs but you can post a screengrab of the PDF.

Comment: I fixed your image markup. Use the preview to check your post before posting. You had nested several image instances inside each other. Cropping out the irrelevant parts is a good idea too.

Comment: Please appreciate that I am having difficulties using the format of this website, and I can only respond to comments to the level of my knowledge and ability to work with this format, and to my own particular time scale.  Thank you for those that are editing and fixing up problems with this post question.

Comment: @ChrisBattle - Hi, I looked at your question to see if I could help, and I'm not sure about the premise of the question e.g. about pin 25. How did you identify any pin, as pin 25? The pin labels on the DVM schematic (thanks for adding the link) don't match the MAX134 datasheet. Just one example: schematic says pin 18 is the beeper; datasheet says (on that PLCC package) that it's pin 11. The datasheet shows pin number 1 is *not* at a corner of the package, the schematic says that it is! I suggest finding unique pins (e.g. those connected to the crystal) to try to sort out those contradictions.

Comment: Yes, Sam, the problem is that I can't find a datasheet that pertains to the subject IC.  However, what the schematic shows on the right hand side of U2 checks out OK, because I have traced the tracks from the RN1 to their respective pins 25-28.  In the photo of the MAX134 I posted, there is a dot in the bottom left of the chip, and the numbers start counter-clockwise from that corner.  Also, VR2 is connected to the voltage reference pin 34 as it is depicted at the top right of U2 on the schematic.

Comment: The problem with this meter is that the the diode tester function is not working (won't change from displaying "OPEn" and 3.999V), nor the 4VDC range, and it appears that they are related somehow.  On the 4VDC range, the display alternates between showing 3.999V and 0V.  If a voltage is measured, say a 1.5V cell, then the display will alternate between showing 3.999V and 1.5V.

Comment: The MAX134CMH-D ADC chip is a MQFP44 type, and MAXIM has apparently never provided a pinout for it!  None of the datasheets on the internet provide any information about the MQFP44 configuration .....very strange!  I did find a hand-drawn pinout on a Russian forum, and I have added that image to this post.

Comment: Pay attention that pin 1 is in a different position with respect to the first attached drawing, it is not in the highlighted corner but in the center of the side.
Take a closer look at the datasheet.

Answer (score 1):

The value of that capacitor can be deduced simply.
In the diagram the capacitance ends in 00pF, the remaining capacitors show uF or no suffix for nF, therefore considering the standard values of the capacitors that end in 00 there is only 100.
It cannot be 1000pF because they would have written it as 1nF or 100 (1x 10E0).

Answer (score 0):

The value of the capacitor C58, is effectively 100pF[image]